# Take column names from old dataframe in Spark Scala

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark

See my code:

```
 val spark = SparkSession.builder
      .master("local[*]")
      .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer")
      .getOrCreate()


    val data = spark.read.option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema", "true")
      .csv("src/main/resources/student.csv")
```

My data looks like:

```
Id   Name  City  
1    Ali   lhr
2    abc   khi
3    xyz   isb
```

Now I create a new DataFrame:

```
 val someDF = Seq(
      (4,"Ahmad","swl")
    ).toDF("Id", "Name","City")
```

Here you can see I have created a new DataFrame `someDF` with same column name as old DataFrame `data`. But I have assigned names manually to the new DataFrame `someDF`. My question is that is there any method that can take column names from old DataFrame and assign it to new DataFrame programmatically.

Something like

```
val featureCols= data.columns
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.toDF` accepts **`(colNames: String*)`** , We can unnest `List[String]` as strings with **`:_*`**

**`Example:`**

```
val featureCols=Seq("Id","Name","City")
val someDF = Seq((4,"Ahmad","swl").toDF(cols:_*)

Seq(("1","2","3")).toDF(featureCols:_*).show()
//+---+----+----+
//| Id|Name|City|
//+---+----+----+
//|  1|   2|   3|
//+---+----+----+
```

Comment: Can't we take column names from old DataFrame?

Comment: @AyezaMalik, yes can use **`val featureCols= data.columns`**

Comment: ```val someDF = Seq(
      (4,"Ahmad","swl")
    ).toDF(featureCols :_*)```
right ?

Answer (score 1):

2 ways to do it pass column array as varargs i.e. (data.columns:_*)  & union. below is the full example.

```
  val csv =
    """
      |Id,Name,  City
      |1,Ali,lhr
      |2,abc,khi
      |3,xyz,isb
    """.stripMargin.lines.toSeq.toDS()
//*** Option1***
  val data: DataFrame = spark.read.option("header", true)
    .option("sep", ",")
    .option("inferSchema", true)
    .csv(csv)
  data.show
  val someDF: DataFrame = Seq(
    (4,"Ahmad","swl")
  ).toDF(data.columns:_*)
  someDF.show

  //***Option 2***
  val someDF1: DataFrame = Seq(
    (4,"Ahmad","swl")
  ).toDF
  data.limit(0).union(someDF1).show
```

Result :

```
+---+----+------+
| Id|Name|  City|
+---+----+------+
|  1| Ali|   lhr|
|  2| abc|   khi|
|  3| xyz|   isb|
+---+----+------+

+---+-----+------+
| Id| Name|  City|
+---+-----+------+
|  4|Ahmad|   swl|
+---+-----+------+

+---+-----+------+
| Id| Name|  City|
+---+-----+------+
|  4|Ahmad|   swl|
+---+-----+------+
```

Comment: I was actually looking for ```option1```.